# Dismiss Power Off System Dialog

Tags: dialog

I would like to know how to dismiss the Power off System Dialog programmatically when a hardware button is pressed.

`Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS` closes all the system dialogs. I would like to close only the power off system dialog.